# Formal array type with the declared number of indexes (generic package)

Tags: ada

Generic package specification:

```ada
generic
   type Real is digits <>;
   type Real_Arr is array (Integer range <>) of Real;
package Pack1 is
   function Gt (A : in Real; B : in Real_Arr) return Boolean;
end Pack1;
```

Generic package body:

```ada
package body Pack1 is
   function Gt (A : in Real; B : in Real_Arr) return Boolean
   is
     (for all X of B => (X > A));
end Pack1;
```

For a function `Gt`, the dimension of `B` is not important.

How can I do something like that?

```ada
generic
   type Real is digits <>;
   --  Declare number of indexes?
   --  N : Positive;
   --  type Real_Arr is array (??? N ???) of Real;
package Pack1 is
```

And use with different types:

```ada
with Pack1;
package Math is
   --  Array types are outside of generic package!
   type Vector is array (Positive range <>) of Float;
   type Matrix is array (Positive range <>, Positive range <>) of Float;

   package Opv is new Pack1 (Float, 1, Vector);
   package Opm is new Pack1 (Float, 2, Matrix);
end Math;
```

I want to do this because the implementation of the function `Gt` is the same for arrays with any indexes and dimensions.

Comment: You must have separate generics for different numbers of dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to give the number `N` and then have the package to declare a function that takes an array of `N` values. Do this:

```ada
generic
   type Real is digits <>;
   N : Positive;
package Pack1 is
   type Real_Arr is array (1 .. N) of Real;
   --  ...
end Pack1;
```

Note that the array type is not a generic parameter; instead, the package declares the type based on the given generic parameter `N`.

You could, of course, also take the array type as generic parameter, if your array type already exists outside the package.

Comment: No, I want to give number of indexes `N` of array type.

Comment: You want to give the number of dimensions? That's not possible.